# RxJava - Wait till retryWhen finish for other observables in other Activities/Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, rx-java, reactive-programming

**Usecase:** I am developing an Android app with has a viewpager with 4 tabs, all of them are Fragments. For each tab/fragment I have to connect to a REST Api with Oauth and token expiration every 5 minutes.

**Current Solution:** Using RxJava and retryWhen operator I can re-authenticate when receive an 401 HTTP Error. For every Observable stream subscribed and consumed and use the:

```
retryWhen(refreshTokenAuthenticator)
```

So when the token expires the stream consume it and then execute the real api call.

**Problem:** this only works for one observable consumed in one subscribed but I need to allow the user to switch between tabs without blocking him/her taking into account that the 401 Error could appear in any time in any fragment in any Api Call.

**Question:** Is there a way to make observables wait for other observables finish with *onNext()* which are not in the same stream/subscriber? In fact in different Fragments? So the api call scenarios will be like this:

```
Api Call Fragment A --> request
Api Call Fragment A <-- response 200 Code

Api Call Fragment B --> request
Api Call Fragment B <-- response 401 Code (retryWhen in action)
Api Call Fragment B --> request (refreshToken)
Api Call Fragment B <-- response 200 (with new access token saved in the app)
```

Almost at the same time...

```
Api Call Fragment C --> request
Api Call Fragment C <-- response 401 Code (retryWhen in action)
```

---

```
Observable in Fragment C Waits till Observable in Fragment B finish (onNext())
```

---

```
Api Call Fragment C --> request
Api Call Fragment C <-- response 200
```

This is what I already have, each API call looks almost the same:

```
public void getDashboardDetail() {

    Subscription subscription = repository.getDashboard()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .retryWhen(tokenAuthenticator)
            .subscribe(new RestHttpObserver<UserDataDto>() {
                @Override
                public void onUnknownError(Throwable e) {
                    getMvpView().onError(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onHostUnreachable() {
                    getMvpView().onHostUnreachable();
                }

                @Override
                public void onHttpErrorCode(int errorCode, ErrorDto errorDto) {
                    getMvpView().onHttpErrorCode(errorCode, errorDto);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    //Do nothing...
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(UserDataDto response) {
                    getMvpView().onReceiveUserData(response);
                }
            });

    this.compositeSubscription.add(subscription);

}
```

And my RefreshTokenAuthenticator:

```
public class RefreshTokenAuthenticator implements Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>> {

private static final int RETRY_COUNT = 1;

private static final int HTTP_ERROR_CODE = 401;

@Inject
private UserRepository repository;

@Inject
private SessionManager sessionManager;

@Inject
private MyApplication application;


@Inject
private RefreshTokenAuthenticator() {
}

@Override
public synchronized Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> observable) {
    return observable
            .flatMap(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
                int retryCount = 0;

                @Override
                public Observable<?> call(final Throwable throwable) {

                    retryCount++;
                    if (retryCount <= RETRY_COUNT && throwable instanceof HttpException) {
                        int errorCode = ((HttpException) throwable).code();
                        if (errorCode == HTTP_ERROR_CODE) {
                            return repository
                                    .refreshToken(sessionManager.getAuthToken().getRefreshToken())
                                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

                                    .doOnNext(tokenDto -> sessionManager.saveAuthToken(tokenDto))
                                    .doOnError(throwable1 -> {
                                        Log.e("RefreshTokenAuth", "DoOnError", throwable1);
                                        application.logout();
                                    });

                        }
                    }
                    // No more retries. Pass the original Retrofit error through.
                    return Observable.error(throwable);
                }
            });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

1) Make source of auth tokens cache last successful result + provide method to invalidate this cached result:

```
class Auth {
    private Observable<AuthToken> validToken;

    synchronized void invalidateAuthToken() {
        validToken = null;
    }

    synchronized Observable<AuthToken> getAuthToken() {
        if (validToken == null) {
            validToken = repository
                .refreshToken(...) // start async request
                .doOnError(e -> invalidateAuthToken())
                .replay(1); // cache result
        }
        return validToken; // share among all subscribers
    }
}
```

2) To access web service use the following pattern:

```
Observable<Data1> dataSource1 = 
    Observable.defer(auth.getAuthToken()) // always start from token
        .flatMap(token ->
            repository.fetchData1(token, ...)) // use token to call web service
        .doOnError(e -> auth.invalidateAuthToken())
        .retry(N); // retry N times
```

Comment: I am using and interceptor with Retrofit 2 to intercept the request and append the header with the token. Do you think your answer (using authtoken in a Rx way) is a better or at least more easy to handle?

Comment: @NicolasJafelle My example is generic. You can implement `fetchData1` function so it injects token in Retrofit way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally make it work just adding a global (in my Application class) boolean if the app is currently re-authenticating or not. It actually allows two 401 HTTP errors but the second one continues in the onNext() and re execute the initial observable. I would like to do something more reactive but at least this solves my main problem.

```
public class RefreshTokenAuthenticator implements Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>> {

private static final int RETRY_COUNT = 1;

private static final int HTTP_ERROR_CODE = 401;

@Inject
private UserRepository repository;

@Inject
private SessionManager sessionManager;

@Inject
private MyApplication application;


@Inject
private RefreshTokenAuthenticator() {
}

@Override
public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> observable) {
    return observable
            .flatMap(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
                int retryCount = 0;

                @Override
                public Observable<?> call(final Throwable throwable) {

                    retryCount++;
                    if (retryCount <= RETRY_COUNT && throwable instanceof HttpException) {
                        int errorCode = ((HttpException) throwable).code();

                        if (errorCode == HTTP_ERROR_CODE) {

                            Log.i("RefreshTokenAuth", "APPLICATION IS AUTHENTICATING = " + application.isAuthenticating);
                            if (!application.isAuthenticating) {
                                application.isAuthenticating = true;

                                String refreshToken = sessionManager.getAuthToken().getRefreshToken();

                                return repository
                                        .refreshToken(refreshToken)
                                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                        .doOnCompleted(() -> application.isAuthenticating = false)
                                        .doOnNext(tokenDto -> sessionManager.saveAuthToken(tokenDto))
                                        .doOnError(throwable1 -> {
                                            Log.e("RefreshTokenAuth", "DoOnError", throwable1);
                                            application.logout();
                                        });
                            } else {
                                return Observable.just(1).doOnNext(o -> Log.i("RefreshTokenAuth", "Let's try another shot!"));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // No more retries. Pass the original Retrofit error through.
                    return Observable.error(throwable);
                }
            });
}
```

}